# Spring MVC JSP page reload

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

In my spring mvc application,I am facing a problem of page reloading on every request.Is there any way to restrict that.To be more specific,When I return the name of index.jsp page from controller it will obviously reload the page.How Can I restrict that thing in the index.jsp page.Suppose some part of the page is required to interact with Database and it should be shown on the same index.jsp page as well.How I can achieve this requirement without reloading the index.jsp page completely.Could you please provide me some example for that.

Comment: could any body please provide any knowledge on why this is marked as low vote.Please provide me some comment as this is very important question for me as of now.I am stuck in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understand correctly you want to update some parts of your page in asynk way.

You have to use ajax. Take a look on the web. There are so many frameworks that could simplify your life.. one is jquery for example